# Simple Horizontal Button Bar for iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, components, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I have a requirement for a very simple Button Bar.

- It should take up the width of the screen.
- It should allow at least 3
  buttons.
- The buttons should be of equal width and together take up
  the whole width of the bar.
- Each button should be tappable, but not
  have a selected state.
- The bar will be overlaid on a MapView and positioned directly above a TabBar.
- Tapping a button will launch a Modal ViewController.

I thought about using a UITabBar and not allowing its tabs to become selected, but the HIG is pretty clear that this is not correct usage and UIToolBar doesn't allow the button widths to be set.

This seems like a very simple requirement but I can't see an obvious solution. Is there something I'm missing? Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just creating a simple view that draws an appropriate gradient, and then adding three buttons of the appropriate size?

If you're feeling ambitious, or if this is something that you're likely to use more than once, you could even have the view create the three buttons. Call it `ThreeButtonBar` or something. Give it a constant height and adjust the width to match that of its superview so that you can use it in portrait or landscape orientation.

Comment: That's a fair comment. You're right in that it is a simple thing I'm after. I was just surprised that there was no way of doing this with the component-set at hand. I thought I must be missing something.